# Sharing my home folders with other users on the same PC

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, encryption, home-directory, shared-folders

After reviewing similar questions on the same subject Im still none the wiser.  I want to share my music, pictures and video folders with other users on my pc.  I am using 11.10 and will be upgrading to 12.04. The method I have tried is to right click on the folder (as Administrator), select "Sharing Options" check all the necessary fields and give the share a name like "music-shared".  Another dialog pops up then and I select "Set nautilus Permissions".
When the other user logs on they go to their Home folder click on the network and can see the "music-shared" folder, but they get a message that the do not have the necessary permissions to view the content.  Im sure I'm missing something simple. My Home folder is encrypted and i am willing to unencrypt to make this work  Unlike other questions on this site, I dont have a partition etc.  i would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Sharing an encrypted folder is unlikely to work. Unless there is a compelling reason to encrypt your music, use a different folder outside your home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to

1. Create a folder called /shared;
2. Create a group with any name, such
   as mediamembers, and add all the users to it. Alternatively, you can
   allow everyone access);
3. Set yourself as owner, and group as mediamembers (sudo chown -R
   yourname:mediamembers /shared;  alternatively, just set the
   permissions for /shared to whatever you want for group and the rest
   of the world;
4. Create subdirectories for video, music, pictures, and move the files there from your home
   directory;
5. Create symbolic links to these directories in you home directory's
   subdirectories;
6. In the future, follow the symbolic link to the shared directory to save files.

You could even mount the directory, and in the future, if your media collection got too big, you could put it on a separate disk and mount that in the same place with no changes for the users.

I have mine on a separate partition to solve a different problem, which is to easily access these file when I install a new distro for testing, etc.  I just mount the shared partition, and have everything there.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea (1-5) and I may experiment with your solution with mounting a partition as this would solve all my problems. Theres no need for the shared folders and files to be encrypted.

Comment: Hope it works for you.  I had to do it because my media files were simply taking up too much space.  Now, with a separate partition, I never have to worry about saving a big file and having it suddenly eat up all my available free space, which could cause problems.  PS. I edited my answer, as two of my list items got formatted incorrectly into one - in case anyone gets confused by your reference to "1-5" (now 1-6). :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't share an encrypted folder, that's why it is encrypted.

But you can try to do this, as a workaround:

```
cd ~
sudo mv Music /usr/share/
ln -s /usr/share/Music Music
chmod a+rw /usr/share/Music
```

It'll move your music folder to `/usr/share/`, create a Symlink into your home folder, and allow other users to read/write that folder.

But to be honest, I don't believe it is a good idea to do this.
You may have problems if you need to backup your data and forget that your files are not at the home folder.